# How to prove that $Z[i]/7$ is a field?

Tags: ring-theory

I know that $Q[i]$ is a field since we can find the inverse for each $a+bi$ namely $\frac{a}{a^2+b^2} - i\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}$. However, I am not sure how to do so for something like $Z[i]/7$ since we can only have non-negative integers less than 7 as coefficients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: the same method of rationalizing the denominator works over any field where $\,-1\,$ is not a square, since then $\,a^2+b^2\neq 0,\,$ for else $\,b = 0 \,\Rightarrow\,a= 0,\,$ contra $\,a+bi\neq 0,\,$ and $\, b\neq 0\,\Rightarrow\, (a/b)^2 = -1,\,$ contra hypothesis that $\, -1\,$ is not a square  (as is true in $\,\Bbb Z/7).$

More generally one can rationalize denominators of algebraic numbers by taking norms (multiplying by conjugates), or by reading off the inverse from a polynomial having it as root.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: You have the right formula to find the inverse of any element, the only problem is that the denominator $a^2+b^2$ might be zero (contained in the ideal generated by $7$). Why can this not happen?

Comment: I think I got that $a^2+b^2 \neq 0$ but I am still quite confused. So if I want to find the inverse of, say $(3+4i)$. Then, I can take $\frac{3}{25} - i\frac{4}{25}$ but how do I make that in $Z[i]/7$?

Comment: Calculate the fractions mod $7,\,$ e.g. $\, 3/25\equiv 3/(-3)\equiv -1\equiv 6,\,$ and $\,-4/35\equiv 3/25\equiv 6,\,$ so the inverse is $\equiv 6+6i,\,$ indeed $(3+4i)(6+6i)=42i-6\equiv -6\equiv 1.$

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{Z}[i]/(7)$ is a field. From standard results in ring theory, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID, so all nonzero prime ideals are maximal. Also, the quotient of a ring (for our purposes, say commutative and with identity) by a maximal ideal is a field. In our case, $(7)$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ hence maximal. Therefore $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(7)$ is a field.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I meant Q[i] in my first sentence. I will fix it now.

Comment: Excellent, I'll remove the first sentence in my answer since it is no longer relevant.

Comment: Also, thanks for the proof using maximal ideal. I totally forgot about that when I saw the question. But I think my original intent was to find explicitly the inverse, so I think I will go with the other one.

Comment: @dc2814 The point is that the same method (rationalizing the denominator) works over any field where $-1$ is not a square.